# Javascript code to dynamically change image works in IE not FF, Chrome etc :(

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, dhtml

Usually I hear about code working under things apart from IE but Ive got the opposite problem.

Here's the link :

http://www.underagedriving.co.uk/ins/timeclick2.php

And a snapshot of the code that doesnt kick any errors under IE but wont play ball with anything else (Opera, iPhone Safari, Chrome, FF)

I know its going to be something daft but having worked on this all day (Im not a proper coder) when it wasnt playing ball my eyes kinda glazed over .

Any help appreciated pointing me in the right direction :)

Thanks, Rik

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = new Array();                                  // Create our array
var convexisting = " ";                                 // Create a blank variable we check later

if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)                               // IE8 and below
{ 
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) 
    { 
        var len = this.length >>> 0; 

        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0; 
        from = (from < 0) 
            ? Math.ceil(from) 
            : Math.floor(from); 
        if (from < 0) 
        from += len; 

        for (; from < len; from++) 
        { 
        if (from in this && 
            this[from] === elt) 
            return from; 
        } 
        return -1; 
    }; 
}   

function toggleimg(itemname)
{
    if (document.getElementById(itemname).src == 'http://www.underagedriving.co.uk/ins/yellow.gif')     // If its yellow that means its not set
    {
        document.getElementById(itemname).src = 'http://www.underagedriving.co.uk/ins/blue.gif';    // Change colour to blue
        arr.push(itemname);                                         // Add item to array
        }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(itemname).src = 'http://www.underagedriving.co.uk/ins/yellow.gif';  // If its already blue, deselect it by turning yellow
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(itemname), 1);                               // Remove it from array

    }   
}

function checkform(form)                                            // On submit fix the array to send to PHP
{
    form.availabilityarray.value = arr.join(",");                   // Concat our array data in a CSV string to submit via the form
        return true ;                                   // Allow submitting of the form data
}

function preprocess()                                   // Has to be a function after body load
{
        // If array ready to be processed

    if (convexisting != " ")                            // Check our test var is not blank
    {
        var arr = convexisting.split(",");                  // Split our CSV data for the grid back into an array
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) toggleimg(arr[i]);         // For each entry in array run toggleimg
    }
}   

</script>

<body onload="javascript:preprocess();">

<form name="claimform" method="POST" action="http://www.underagedriving.co.uk/ins/timeclick2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">

<table width="700" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
<tr>
<td width="200">&nbsp;</td><td width="500"><img src='hours.gif' border=0></td>
</tr>    

<tr><td align='right'> Fri 07/10/2011 &nbsp; </td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col00');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col00' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col01');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col01' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col02');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col02' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col03');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col03' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col04');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col04' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col05');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col05' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col06');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col06' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col07');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col07' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col08');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col08' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col09');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col09' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col10');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col10' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col11');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col11' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col12');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col12' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col13');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col13' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col14');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col14' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col15');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col15' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col16');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col16' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col17');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col17' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col18');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col18' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col19');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col19' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col20');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col20' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col21');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col21' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col22');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col22' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111007row05col23');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111007row05col23' border=0></a></td></tr>
<tr><td align='right'> Sat 08/10/2011 &nbsp; </td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col00');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col00' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col01');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col01' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col02');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col02' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col03');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col03' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col04');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col04' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col05');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col05' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col06');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col06' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col07');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col07' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col08');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col08' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col09');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col09' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col10');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col10' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col11');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col11' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col12');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col12' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col13');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col13' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col14');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col14' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col15');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col15' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col16');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col16' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col17');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col17' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col18');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col18' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col19');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col19' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col20');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col20' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col21');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col21' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col22');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col22' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111008row06col23');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111008row06col23' border=0></a></td></tr>
<tr><td align='right'> Sun 09/10/2011 &nbsp; </td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col00');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col00' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col01');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col01' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col02');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col02' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col03');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col03' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col04');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col04' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col05');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col05' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col06');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col06' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col07');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col07' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col08');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col08' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col09');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col09' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col10');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col10' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col11');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col11' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col12');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col12' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col13');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col13' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col14');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col14' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col15');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col15' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col16');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col16' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col17');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col17' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col18');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col18' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col19');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col19' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col20');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col20' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col21');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col21' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col22');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col22' border=0></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggleimg('20111009row07col23');"><img src='yellow.gif' name='20111009row07col23' border=0></a></td></tr>
<tr><td> <hr </td></tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="availabilityarray" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Hours">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chromium states: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null (timeclick2.php:34)`. BTW: `if(convexisting != " ")` Does not check whether the test var is not blank, but if the var does contain anything other than a single space-char.

Comment: In non IE the graphics do not toggle between yellow and blue.

Comment: feeela - yes that is correct. When I used code to check if the variable was set or not I kept getting undefined errors so for simplicities sake on the first run of the script it sets the var to a space and when it runs the second time (eg: data is posted into the script) PHP echo's the proper values into convexisting which then gets picked up and processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name=` attribute is meaningless on the `<img>` tags. If what you actually want is an id, then set the `id=` explicitly.

You may want to familiarize yourself with the jQuery JS library. It makes a lot of tasks like this much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Simply changing the name= to id= part worked (on my iPhone at least as I dont have anything bar IE on my netbook here). :)

Comment: The name **attribute** is not meaningless. It is a valid attribute for *img* elements that can be used for selecting an individual element (if it is unique in the document) or for selecting a group of elements that share the name. The OP's problem is that a name attribute value is being used with a method that expects an ID. It works in IE because IE doesn't know the difference between an element's ID and a NAME attribute or property, browsers conforming to the relevant W3C specifications do.

Comment: Wow, you're right -- I just checked the HTML4 spec, and `name=` is defined on the `<img>` tag. It's only "included for backwards compatibility", though, so using `id=` is still probably the right long-term solution.

Comment: Yes, use id. See my full answer for why the original code worked in IE (I suspect it would work in some versions of Opera too, and maybe some versions of Firefox in quirks mode). The *name* attribute for image elements is not deprecated in HTML5, it has simply been omitted (which is a very strange thing to do). HTML5 is not a standard (it may never be), but HTML 4.01 is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the value of the *name* attribute but using it with *getElementById*, which works on the *id* attribute. Since each name attribute value is unique, you can just change them to id attributes and the code should work. Or you can change the call to [getElementById](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) to [getElementsByName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259).

Since *getElementsByName* returns a collection, if you adopt that approach you'll need to select the first member of the returned collection, something like:

```
if (document.getElementsByName(itemname)[0].src ...)
```

But to be robust, you would need:

```
var el = document.getElementsByName(itemname)[0];
if (el && el.src == ...) {
    ...
}
```

A similar approach should be adopted with the call to *getElementById*.

The code using *getElementById* works in IE (and some browsers that mimic its behaviour) because it has always confused name and id attributes, treating them essentially as the same thing. It doesn't work in standards compliant browsers, and probably won't work in IE 9 in standards mode.

Comment: Thanks Rob, got a fuller understanding of why it works one way and not another :)